# How to get value of only one button that was clicked in a set of buttons that have the same class in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

I'm working on an assignment and I'm having trouble getting the attribute value of **only one** button `onclick`. Only problem is they share the same class and all trigger the same function with an inline `onclick`. So when i loop through all instances of that class, it calls all the attribute values into the console when you click on any button, like so:

```
red
green
blue
```

How do i get the attribute value of only the button i click on?

I tried using `this` but i as i understand it, it's not possible to use `this` with modern JS function syntax. I modified it to `const inline = function() {...}` and `this` still wouldn't work. Any other methods to accomplish this?

Thanks!

```
<div>
    <h3>inline</h3>
    <button class="color" style="background-color: red; color: white;" type="button" onclick="inline()" data-value="red">Red</button>
    <button class="color" style="background-color: green; color: white;" type="button" onclick="inline()" data-value="green">Green</button>
    <button class="color" style="background-color: blue; color: white;" type="button" onclick="inline()" data-value="blue">Blue</button>
</div>
```

```
const inline = () => {
    let color = document.querySelectorAll('.color');
    // let color = this;
    for (let i = 0; i < color.length; i++) {
        console.log(color[i].getAttribute("data-value"));
    }
}
```

Comment: call inline like `inline(this)` ... then if you `const inline = button =>` button will be the one that's clicked ... alternatively use `addEventListener` rather than `onclick=` for a better experience

Comment: note: `color[i].getAttribute("data-value")` is better written `color[i].dataset.value`

Comment: @Bravo Thanks! that did the trick... figured `this` was the solution, just wasn't sure how to apply it. And yep, assignment also requires doing the same thing with event listeners and dot notation. Much more familiar working with those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass through `event` to your `inline()` function call, and then use `e.currentTarget` to get the button element which triggered the event. This way you can get its colour by using `dataset` on the target of the event.

See example below:

```js
const inline = e => {
  let btn = e.currentTarget;
  let color = btn.dataset.value;
  console.log(color);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>inline</h3>
  <button class="color" style="background-color: red; color: white;" type="button" onclick="inline(event)" data-value="red">Red</button>
  <button class="color" style="background-color: green; color: white;" type="button" onclick="inline(event)" data-value="green">Green</button>
  <button class="color" style="background-color: blue; color: white;" type="button" onclick="inline(event)" data-value="blue">Blue</button>
</div>
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to use [`event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event) (due to its fragility), you could pass through `this` instead of `event`, which will refer to the button clicked like so:

```js
const inline = btn => {
  let color = btn.dataset.value;
  console.log(color);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>inline</h3>
  <button class="color" style="background-color: red; color: white;" type="button" onclick="inline(this)" data-value="red">Red</button>
  <button class="color" style="background-color: green; color: white;" type="button" onclick="inline(this)" data-value="green">Green</button>
  <button class="color" style="background-color: blue; color: white;" type="button" onclick="inline(this)" data-value="blue">Blue</button>
</div>
```

However, it's often not a good idea to mix HTML and JS together as you should keep your markup and JS logic separate. So, instead, you should consider using event listeners within your JS code by looping over all button elements:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".color").forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    const color = this.dataset.value;
    console.log(color);
  });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>inline</h3>
  <button class="color" style="background-color: red; color: white;" type="button" data-value="red">Red</button>
  <button class="color" style="background-color: green; color: white;" type="button" data-value="green">Green</button>
  <button class="color" style="background-color: blue; color: white;" type="button" data-value="blue">Blue</button>
</div>
```

Comment: the global microsoft abomination `window.event` is not standard at all, and while it works in many browsers, it is considered fragile and should not be used

Comment: @Bravo I wasn't aware of that, thanks for pointing that out. I've updated my answer

Comment: Thanks! Second solution is what i used. Roger on the event listeners, assignment is to work with multiple event handlers. Marking yours correct since @Bravo didn't have a dedicated post.